# Python spawns threads on socket.connect() according to Windows Task Manager

Tags: python, windows, sockets

After executing:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('www.example.com', 80))
```

Amount of threads, as reported by Windows Task Manager jumps up from 1 to 4. My Python version is Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.

I'm tracking a bigger bug that causes a simple reduce() with primitive parameters to hang, and found out this.

I have examined Python's socket.py, and it contains no references whatsoever to threading module. I also skimmed through relevant C source files, and I'm still clueless so as to this behaviour.

Spawning does not seem to happen until successful connection. Spawning does not occur if IP address is passed instead of domain name.
Spawning does occur if ('127.0.0.1', some_port) is passed as target address - but with a single extra thread instead of 3.

Why is that so, that threads are spawned on a simple socket.connect()? Is that normal?

Comment: What [the script](https://gist.github.com/779332f9e5c148bc69f7) shows?

Comment: Shows alternating 2's and 5's. After that, displays the received data from stackexchange.com, and the two last lines are a 2 and 5.

Comment: `2` is the number of Python threads (expected), `5` is what task manager should show (if you installed `psutil`) (unexpected). Related: [Winsock is creating its own threads!](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=306254).

Comment: What [it shows with `socket.getaddrinfo()`](https://gist.github.com/779332f9e5c148bc69f7/b0af2b3d63f3ef760cfdbd1c9e345f02570eab00)?

Comment: 3
2
5
and then HTTP headers.

Result of socket.getaddrinfo() per se is [(2, 1, 0, '', ('64.34.119.12', 80))].

Yes, it's probably the case of Winsock spawning it's own threads. Thanks for pointing that out.